# E-commerce design flow

Tags: e-commerce

I am currently in the process of developing an ecommerce website and I would like to know of any sources that can give an example of the design flow of an ecommerce site, for example from choosing a product to checking it out and any standards to document such process flow? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

There are many aspects to a good UI design for an e-commerce website. I'll point you out to a few good resources.

[NN group's E-Commerce User Experience listing](http://www.nngroup.com/reports/e-commerce-user-experience/) has a good collection of reports about different features that an e-commerce website would typically employ. You can read lookup what you need from here. They are however quite detailed, you may want to have a clear picture in mind as to what you want and then go on about reading.

If you are building it from the bottoms up, you would want to know about THE very basics like fonts, colors, alignment etc. The [e-commerce design fundamentals for optimum usability](http://www.ecommercejuice.com/2012/08/ecommerce-design-fundamentals-for-optimum-usability/) is a good guide for these basic standrds to keep in mind.

There is always a payment process involved in an e-commerce website and I would highly recommend you to read the fundamental guidlines given here ---> [Fundamental guidelines of e-commerce checkout design](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/06/fundamental-guidelines-of-e-commerce-checkout-design/).

Although I would highly recommend you these links, however they are by no means the holy grail to follow. I would advise you to rather look through the general guidelines given in those links, come up with a simple mockup and revise it by looking up design improvements on individual features provided on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Many of those methods like checkout etc. are standarized by widely used e-commerce platforms such as Magento or Woocomerce. Users know these methods and you can focus on designing the user experience rather than rethinking the interface.

Comment: it seems like they were asking about the process flow rather than the UI.